# Issue trying to make a .glb model spin after using gltfjsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, jsx

I've used a `gltf` to `jsx` converter on Github (https://github.com/pmndrs/gltfjsx) to create JSX components of my model. However, I'm struggling to understand how to adjust my `model.js` so that the model automatically spins on its axis. Could anyone help me with this?

```js
import React, { useRef } from 'react'
import { useGLTF } from '@react-three/drei'


export default function Model({ ...props }) {
  const group = useRef()
  const { nodes, materials } = useGLTF('/model.glb')
  return (
    <group ref={group} {...props} dispose={null}>
      <group position={[-0.0, -0.3, -1]} rotation={[-Math.PI / 2, 0, 2.7]} scale={0.58}>
        <mesh geometry={nodes.boot_0.geometry} material={nodes.boot_0.material} />
        <mesh geometry={nodes.boot001_0.geometry} material={nodes.boot001_0.material} />
        <mesh geometry={nodes.boot002_0.geometry} material={nodes.boot002_0.material} />
        <mesh geometry={nodes.boot003_0.geometry} 
        </group>
      </group>
      <group position={[-0.02, -0.01, 0.06]} rotation={[-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0]} scale={0.58}/>
    </group>
  )
}

useGLTF.preload('/model.glb')
```

Comment: If you are free to choose your own solution, I would recommend to have a look at https://modelviewer.dev by Google. It's performant, easy to integrate and you can configure the viewer to have a rotation animation. You can setup everything from the editor.

Answer (score 0):

Simply import the `useFrame` hook from **'@react-three/fiber'**, and set the x-axis adjustment accordingly. In your case, it would look like this:

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react'
import { useGLTF } from '@react-three/drei'
import { useFrame } from '@react-three/fiber'  // Import the useFrame hook

export default function Model({ ...props }) {

  const group = useRef()
  const { nodes, materials } = useGLTF('/model.glb')

  // We utilize the useFrame hook here to rotate on the x-axis.
  useFrame(() => {
    group.current.rotation.x += .02;
  })

  return (
    <group ref={group} {...props} dispose={null}>
      <group position={[-0.0, -0.3, -1]} rotation={[-Math.PI / 2, 0, 2.7]} scale={0.58}>
        <mesh geometry={nodes.boot_0.geometry} material={nodes.boot_0.material} />
        <mesh geometry={nodes.boot001_0.geometry} material={nodes.boot001_0.material} />
        <mesh geometry={nodes.boot002_0.geometry} material={nodes.boot002_0.material} />
        <mesh geometry={nodes.boot003_0.geometry} 
        </group>
      </group>
      <group position={[-0.02, -0.01, 0.06]} rotation={[-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0]} scale={0.58}/>
    </group>
  )
}

useGLTF.preload('/model.glb')
```